# Best place to upload xml (for referring in this site)

Tags: discussion, questions

Many a times we need to refer some huge files while asking a question in this site. If I have a question regarding HTML, CSS or jQuery I can use jsFiddle to upload the content.

In the case of XML file (for example WSDL) what is the best place for uploading and referring?

What are the most popular site for this?

Reference:

1. [Is it encouraged to refer jsFiddle?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3993/is-it-encouraged-to-refer-jsfiddle)
2. http://www.awwwards.com/10-html-css-online-code-editors-for-web-developers.html
3. Dabblet, Thimble, by Mozilla, jsFiddle, jsBin, Cloud9, CodeMirror, eXo Cloud IDE, CodeRun, Compilr, Codeanywhere, Kodingen, Google Developers

Comment: Sounds like a meta question.

Comment: @Tichodroma - it's also not answerable.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is that you shouldn't be referring to huge files when asking questions.

All the information should be in the question body and you should have the minimal amount of data/code/whatever that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Programmers is a conceptual site where there should be no need to refer to any large file for a question.

If a question about WSDL files requires reference to a specific WSDL file it's not conceptual any more, it's an implementation issue which is off topic.