# Is it encouraged to refer jsFiddle?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have a HTML related question.  In stack overflow / programmers, is it a good practice to refer code shared in jsFiddle? Or should I post the code in the question itself?

Comment: the need to link to jsFiddle to ask a question on programmers is probably a good indication this is the wrong site to be asking on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first instance why are you asking on Meta **Programmers** rather than Meta **Stack Overflow**?

However, to answer your question - you should post the minimal code that reproduces the problem in the body of the question. Don't make people go to an external resource for the code.

Personally I wouldn't follow the link.

There's nothing wrong with linking to the same code as a jsFiddle if it helps demonstrate the problem, but the question should stand alone.